# How to use vite with Laravel to minify css and js

Tags: laravel-8, vite, laravel-9

I am using an **HTML template** with Laravel and for every page write my custom js and CSS for features.

I want to use vitejs to minify all my js and CSS files

Like any changes in the js file (filename.js) in the project-root/resources/js directory

vitejs work in the background and update the file (filename.min.js) in the project-root/public/js directory

and same for css

reference:

https://vitejs.dev/config/build-options.html#build-minify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/vite

Once you have it setup you

`npm run dev`

to get updated css/js files during development

and `npm run build` to generate minified files to deploy